# Pass body of request to calling function using node request module

Tags: node.js

I wrote a small module that makes a Get Request using the 'request' module. I want to do call it from another script, and use the result of the Get on the calling function like so:

```
var request = require('request');

function SendGet(uri) {

var outer_body  = "test";
request(uri, function(error, response, body) {
                      console.log(body);
                      outer_body = body;                    
                    });

console.log(outer_body);
return outer_body;
}
exports.GetRequest = SendGet;
```

Then I use it like this:

```
var MyReq = require('./reqtest');
var uri = "http://api.myhost.com";
var result = MyReq.GetRequest(uri);
console.log("My result is:",result);
```

When I run it, I see in the console the body of the response when using the GetRequest but the variable that is returned still has the value used to initialize it:

```
c:\node messages.js
test
My result is: test
<full body here>
c:\
```

How can I pass back the body to the calling function?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var request = require('request');

function SendGet(uri) {

var outer_body = "test";
outer_body = request(uri, function(error, response, body) {
                      console.log(body);
                      return body;                    
                  });

    console.log(outer_body);
    return outer_body;
}
exports.GetRequest = SendGet;
```

Here you are returning the result of your callback to the variable outer_body

Comment: thank you,tried it but what it gets returned is the Request, not the body